# Spring Junit Test try to load the main application context file

Tags: spring, junit4

I have a simple Jms class i want to test using Spring-test and Junit.

Now, the main application use Jms to publish message to a Queue.  I have a specific jms-context.xml that contains all the config for this JmsTemplate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder location="file:env/dev/conf/ingest.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

<!-- Tibco EMS configuration -->
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${tibco.ems.provider.url}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${tibco.ems.username}</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${tibco.ems.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="emsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="${tibco.ems.TopicConnectionFactoryName}" />
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentialsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <ref bean="emsConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="username" value="${tibco.ems.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${tibco.ems.password}" />
</bean>




<!-- EMS Enterprise topic publisher -->
<bean id="jmsTopicPublisher" class="com.scrippsnetworks.ingest.common.message.jms.JmsTopicPublisher">
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
</bean>

<!-- EMS Sender Destination -->
<bean id="enterpriseEventDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="${asset.topic}"/>
</bean>

<!-- EMS Template for enterprise event -->
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="userCredentialsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="enterpriseEventDestination"/>
</bean>
```

In Integration test it is working fine, but for my unit test i use a junit class ike this :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:jms-event-generator-test.xml")
public class JmsEventGeneratorTest {

@Mock
JmsTopicPublisher publisher;

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
EventGenerator messageGenerator;


@Before
public void init() throws Exception {

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);


}
@Test
public void bootstrapTest() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(messageGenerator);

}

@Test
public void testMessageAsset() {
    SarAssetType asset = new SarAssetType();
    asset.setScrid("1234");
    asset.setType("TOTO");
    messageGenerator.generateAssetCreationMessage(asset);
}
```

The jms-context-test file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


<context:property-placeholder location="file:env/dev/conf/ingest.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.ingest.common.message"/>

<bean id="eventHelper" class="com.xxx.common.event.EventHelper"/>
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.xxx.jms.core.JmsTemplate"/>
```

So when i run my junit test above, it fails because it cannot connect to the tibco server!!!!

I notice it because i work remotely and was diconnected from the vpn.

So why does Spring try to load the main application context file with the real tibco stuff??

Regards

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.ingest.common.message"/>` -- possible you have a class annotated with @Configuration somewhere within this package that imports the application context file?

Comment: already checked and no

Comment: @Don Well.. finally that was the problem!  I was checking the main/src and no Configuration  were in the sub package scanned... but i forgot to check the test/src :-S  Moving from XML to Configuration is new for me....